# GoogleScript - convert arrays of different lengths into arrays of the same length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

To be able to use setValues() instead of setValue on a high number of rows, I would like to know how can I convert all my arrays into arrays of the same length.

During a map function, I create one giant array that looks like this :

```
const myArray = [[Monday, Tuesday],[Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday],[Friday],[Monday,Friday],[Tuesday,Wednesday,Friday]] // And so on.
```

At the moment I use a setValue for each item of the array. The next step would be simply to use setValues(), and append an array but the problem is they are all of different lengths.

```
result.forEach(function(_,index){
      currentSheet.getRange(1+index,5).setValue(result[index]);
});
```

That is going to do that for 600 lines and I will do it several times with other functions. I can live with it, but it seems like a waste. Is there a way to make the arrays homogenous (all arrays would be have a length of 3 elements, one or two being empty for example) an use one single setValues() instead ?

EDIT : the original map function to create the first array was requested. Here it is :

(Basically what it does is : it runs a map through a first array, look at the first element and go find in the source all the elements that have the same key and return the 9th and 10th elements of that array)

```
const result = UniquesDatas.map(uniqueRow =>
    SourceDatas
      .filter(row => row[0] === uniqueRow[0])
      .map(row => [row[9]+" "+row[10]])
      );
```

Thank you in advance,

Cedric

Comment: add nulls to make them the same length

Comment: Please, add your map function to see how can we help.

Comment: Can you supply the map function you used to generate the initial array? It should be possible to modify that function instead of iterating over the array of arrays a second time.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the first map.... thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can `concat` an array of empty elements of the remaining length.

```js
const myArray = [['Monday', 'Tuesday'],['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'],['Friday'],['Monday','Friday'],['Tuesday','Wednesday','Friday']]
const res = myArray.map(x => x.concat(Array(3 - x.length)));
console.log(res);
```

As suggested by [Kinglish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772933), to get the length of the inner array with the most elements, use `Math.max(...myArray.map(x=>x.length))`, which will work for the more general case.

Comment: you can replace that hardcoded 3 with a variable from `Math.max(...myArray.map(x=>x.length))`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it is perfect ! Thank you Kinglish for the precision.

Comment: @Cedric Glad to help.

Comment: @Kinglish Good suggestion.